# XSD: Combine Unknown with Required elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to validate an XML with some **required**, and some **unknown** elements.

The problem is that `xs:any` expects to be inside `xs:sequence`

Also the [UPA rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution) applies (does an unknown element belong to `xs:any` or does it belong to an optional element `minOccurs="0"`?).

The XML:

```html
<person>
    <name>John</name>            <!-- required -->
    <address>Lane 1</address>    <!-- optional -->
    <unknown>someValue</unknown> <!-- unknown  -->
    <status>1</status>           <!-- required -->
</person>
```

My best shot (actually: my wish how it should work):

```html
<xs:complexType name="person">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
        <xs:element name="status" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

But according to all documentation, this is not allowed.

I've also tried various ways of nesting, e.g.:

```xml
<xs:all>
    <xs:sequence>
```

However I could not yet find the solution.

Does anyone have a solution how to combine required with unknown elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly simple: use XSD 1.1

Then, the following will actually validate.

Note the `<xs:all>`: correct order of elements is not required anymore.

```xml
<xs:complexType name="person">
    <xs:all>
        <!-- Required -->
        <xs:element name="name"/>
        <xs:element name="status"/>
        <!-- Optional -->
        <xs:element name="address" minOccurs="0"/>
        <!-- Unknown-->
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

(For example, in XMLSpy: tools -> options -> Always v1.1)